# Missing "removing formating" button for the rich text editor

Tags: custom-field, administration, configuration, editor

According to the documents:

1. https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=fields_using_rich_text_area.htm&type=0
2. https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=fields_using_html_editor.htm&language=en_US&type=0
3. https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000KrcBAAS

It supposes to have "removing formatting" button/function in the rich text editor’s WYSIWYG interface.

But, there is no the function actually...
[image: Missing remove formatting function on the rich text editor]

It is the screenshot and there is no "removing formating" function

What config needs to enable/have the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Remove Formatting** button is available in Lightning experience and not in Salesforce Classic. Seems like you're searching for it in Salesforce Classic. Move to lightning experience.

Below is snapshot for the same:

[image]

Refer this [link](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=fields_using_rich_text_area.htm&type=0) for more details

Comment: Yes, I can find it now. It does not mention the difference/limit in the document clearly.